# How to show php dynamic array data in c3js chart?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, c3.js

I have multidimensional array(`$array`) like this,

```
{
"2015-11-17": {
                "department1":"0.5700",
                "department3":"0.0000"
              },
"2015-11-18": { 
                "department1":"0.5700"
              },
"2015-11-20": {
                "department1":"0.0000"
              },
"2015-11-23": {
                "department1":"1.7100",
                "department2":"1.7100",
                "department3":"2.8500",
              }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

This is a dynamic array and that data are get from database. All data are exists in `$array` variable. The above data are more than that. I just show a little, because the data are get from database.

I want to show that data on c3js chart like this format,

```
json:[{
            "date": "2015-11-17",
            "department1": ""0.5700"",
            "department2": "0.0000",
            "department3": "0.0000",
            "department4": "0.0000",
        }],
```

And I need to show four department data for each date.

In the array, you can see some day have one or two department. I want to add all four department for each day when I change above json format to show in chart.

For example, in `2015-11-17`, it has department1 and 3. I want to add next department2 and 4 with '0' in this day.

I want to add another department for each day just like that.

When I try to change `$array` to above format, I don't get the correct result.
Here is what I try,

```
<div id='chart'></div>
    <script>
            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#chart',
                data: {
                    x: 'date',
                    xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
                    json:[
                    <?php 
                        for ($i = 0; $i <  count($array); $i++) {
                            $key=key($array);
                            $val=$array[$key];
                            if ($val<> ' ') {
                                foreach ($val as $k=>$v) {
                    ?>                  
                    {   
                        'date':<?php echo $key?>,
                        <?php echo $k?> : <?php echo $v?>,
                    },                  

                    <?php
                                   }
                               }
                             next($array);
                        }
                    ?>],

                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                },
                line: {
                    width:0.5
                },
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'timeseries',
                        tick:{
                            format: '%Y-%m-%d',
                            rotate: 75,
                        },
                        label: {
                            text: 'Date',
                            position: 'outer-center'
                        }
                    }
                },          
                grid: {
                    y: {
                        show:true,
                    }
                },
            });
    </script>
```

So, now I have problem to show array data in chart. I'm very appreciate for any answer and suggestion.

Here is the sample of dynamic chart image of what I want, [image: sample chart]

Comment: you can do it using query. use Case in your query

Comment: How can I use? Can you show me sample code?

Comment: which database you are using ?

Comment: I use MySQL database.

Comment: send me your data structure. i'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check the below code. Points to note: 
- `$deptNames` = array of department names as shown in example output.
- `$dataArray` = is the array which comes from database directly
- instead of echoing output you can save it to any variable and access accordingly.

```
$deptNames = array('department1','department2','department3','department4');
$resultArray = array();
$index = 0;
foreach($dataArray as $date => $data) {
    $resultArray[$index] = array();
    if(is_array($data)) {
        $dataDeptNames = array_keys($data);
        $diff = array_diff($deptNames,$dataDeptNames);
        if($diff && count($diff) > 0) {
            foreach($diff as $notExistDept) {
                $data[$notExistDept] = "0.0000";
            }
        }
        $resultArray[$index] = $data;
        $resultArray[$index]['date'] = $date;
        ksort($resultArray[$index]);
    }
    $index++;
}
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

It will give you output as:

```
[  
   {  
      "date":"2015-11-17",
      "department1":"0.5700",
      "department2":"0.0000",
      "department3":"0.0000",
      "department4":"0.0000"
   },
   {  
      "date":"2015-11-18",
      "department1":"0.5700",
      "department2":"0.0000",
      "department3":"0.0000",
      "department4":"0.0000"
   },
   {  
      "date":"2015-11-20",
      "department1":"0.0000",
      "department2":"0.0000",
      "department3":"0.0000",
      "department4":"0.0000"
   },
   {  
      "date":"2015-11-23",
      "department1":"1.7100",
      "department2":"1.7100",
      "department3":"2.8500",
      "department4":"0.0000"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you get the array and is stored in a variable, then you can use this pure JS function to convert it to the format you need:

```
var convertArr = function(x){
  var y = [];
  for (var k1 in x) {
    if (x.hasOwnProperty(k1)) {
      var obj = {};
      obj['date'] = k1;
      var tmp = [];
      for (var k2 in x[k1]){
        if (x[k1].hasOwnProperty(k2)){
          tmp.push(k2[k2.length-1]);
          obj[k2] = x[k1][k2];
        }
      }
      var no = ["1","2","3","4"];
      var tmpSet = new Set(tmp);
      var noSet = new Set(no);
      var diff = no.filter(function(z) { return !tmpSet.has(z); })
                   .concat(tmp.filter(function(z){ return !noSet.has(z); }));
      for (var i = 0; i < diff.length; i++){
        obj['department'+diff[i]] = '0.0000';
      }
      y.push(obj);
    }
  }
  return y;
}
```

From there you can proceed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your solution is correct. As per my understanding, it will be better if we processed the data at the server end and our views will do the job of rendering it. Instead of performing logic or iterating over large arrays on the client end.

Comment: So, which way is the best? @AlankarMore or @dvenkatsagar?

Comment: As per my understanding it is better to have business logic processing at server end always.

Comment: This is also useful, if the array is too big, then processing it and returning the data would take little more time even for the server (you would need to wait a little longer,might be a split second). Its your choice, anyway, now a days the clients are also optimized to make calculations quickly(case of three.js and webgl), so in my opinion, this also can be used.